# get ipywidgets to work on Safari

Tags: ipywidgets

I installed latest ipywidgets with conda-forge (`conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets`), and am running the simplest example from the docs:

```
from ipywidgets import interact

def f(x):
    return x

interact(f, x=10);
```

The only thing that happens is that the value 10 is printed to the screen, but no slider appears.

- Python 3.6
- Jupyter Notebook 5.0
- ipywidgets 7.0.3
- Safari

No error message in terminal other than the message:
`[W 23:23:02.979 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20171024232248 (::1) 14.79ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/notebooks/Untitled1.ipynb`

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Or where I can start testing my installation. I used ipywidgets quite a bit in the past with great success.

Comment: After exploring further and trying many things, it finally worked. I am not at all sure why. I found many posts with similar questions. Cannot reproduce the problem at this time.

Comment: Normally, it can be informative to also check the browser debug console for errors.